# Lasso Regression

Tags: regression, cross-validation, lasso-regression

For the lasso (linear regression with L1 regularization) with a fixed value of λ, it is necessary to
use cross–validation to select the best optimization algorithm.

I know for a fact that we can use cross validation to find optimal value of λ, but is it neccesary to use cross validation in case λ is fixed?

Any thoughts please?

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ for this subject

Answer (score 0):

Cross Validation isn't about if your Regularization Parameter is Fixed or not. Its more related to the R^2 metric.

Lets say you consider 100 records and divide your data into 5 sub-datasets , means each sub-data contains 20 records.
Now out of 5 sub-datas , there are 5 different ways to assign anyone of the sub-data as Cross-Validation (CV) Data.

For all these 5 scenarios, we can find out the R^2, and then find out the Average R^2.
This way, you can have a comparison of your R-score with the Average R-score.